# Ember _ How to access to a controller action from a component controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

I'm trying to add some outter functionality to an ember component . The component is the following one :

**app / templates / programmers.hbs**

```
{{echo-hlabel-tf 
   id= "id-test-hlabel"
   class="class-test-hlabel-mio"
   label="Horizontal textfield"
   textValue="..."
   regExp="^([a-z0-9]{5})$"
   errorMsg="Text hasn't five characters"
   fnActionButtonClicked = "sayHello"
}}
```

I'm playing with parameter **'fnActionButtonClicked'** . This parameter represents a function that it's executed, and it's not inside the functionality of the component ( like passing a javascript function as parameter ). I'm newbie, and I don't know exactly the ember way to do this . The template of the component is :

**app / templates / components / echo-hlabel-tf.hbs**

```
<div id="echo-hlabel-tf">
    <span id="{{id}}-echo-hlabel-tf-label" 
          class="{{class}}-echo-hlabel-tf-hlabel">
    {{label}}
</span>
<span id="{{id}}-echo-hlabel-tf-value" 
      class="{{class}}-echo-hlabel-tf-value">
    {{input id='input-id' class='input-class' value=textValue
            focus-out = (action 'validateRegExp' textValue regExp) 
    }}
</span>
<span id="{{id}}-echo-hlabel-tf-error-msg" 
 class="{{class}}-echo-hlabel-tf-error-msg">
    <p id='error-msg' class="error-msg">
        {{errorMsg}}
    </p>
</span>

<div>
    <h2>Testing passing functions to the component</h2>
        <input type="button" {{action "actionButtonClicked"}}/>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see , at the bottom of the template, there's an input type="button" that it's binded with "actionButtonClicked" . The controller of the component is :

**app / components / echo-hlabel-tf.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   classNameBindings:['error'],
   error:false,

   actions: {
    validateRegExp(text,regExpStr,event){
        let regExpObj = new RegExp(regExpStr)
        if(regExpObj.test(text)){
            this.set('error',false);
        }else{
            this.set('error',true);
        }
    },
    actionButtonClicked(){
        console.log('Arrives to the component');
        var action = this.get('fnActionButtonClicked');
        console.log(action);
        // How can I call the function in another controller
        // With parameter fnActionButtonClicked name
    }
 }
});
```

So , The parameter of the template **'fnActionButtonClicked'** (SayHello) will be retrieved in **actionButtonClicked()** via **var action = this.get('fnActionButtonClicked');** .

So, at this point, comes the doubt . As I can't pass a javascript function as a parameter of a template (or at least, I think it's not the right way to do things ), I have created a controller **'sampleController'** to create the action **'sayHello'** ( See parameter fnActionButtonClicked value ) with the following code :

**app / controllers / sample-controller.js**

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   actions:{
    sayHello(){
        console.log("I'm saying hello this time");
    }
  }
```

});

How can I , from **app / components / echo-hlabel-tf.js:actionButtonClicked()** execute the code of **app / controllers / sample-controller.js : sayHello()** ? How can I access from component controller to another controller ? Is this the right way in ember of achieving my goal ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sample-controller.js , you need to create controller for the specific route  `programmers`. so create `app / controllers / programmers.js` file,

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    sayHello(){
      console.log("I'm saying hello this time");
    }
  }
})
```

and Inside the component `app / components / echo-hlabel-tf.js`.

```
actionButtonClicked(){
  console.log('Arrives to the component');
  this.sendAction('fnActionButtonClicked');        
}
```

Comment: Seems it's still not working . I have created the controller in **app / controllers / programmers.js**  , and sended the action as you said, but I'm getting " ember.debug.js:18008 Nothing handled the action 'sayHello'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble. " . Seems it's not finding the method :(

Comment: Are you that you included component `echo-hlabel-tf.hbs`  in programmers.hbs template ?

Comment: Have a look at [this twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/bdf7e30a0e312b0984696e0891715a23?openFiles=components.echo-hlabel-tf.js%2Ctemplates.components.echo-hlabel-tf.hbs) I created for you.

Comment: Yes . The code of **programmers.hbs**  hasn't changed as the first code I posted in this thread . I'm watching the component in the template , so I guess this part is ok . Do I have to import something ?

Comment: Thanks for the twiddle . I'm taking a look on it . Thanks a lot jeje

Comment: you can try it in twiddle and update non working twiddle, it will help us to figure it out

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry ... I'm sure you are going to hate me after that jajaja ... you were completely right from the beginning . Just, I created a controller with name **programmer.hbs** instead of **programmers.hbs** jejeje ... It was really weird . Sorry for making you loose your time , and thanks again :)